# Google Places API example

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

## The Problem

I've been trying to get [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) google maps API example working but after copying the code exactly from google's site, the example fails to render properly. ie the map completely fails to render, search bar is -350px of the page ect.

*To see what I mean, check out this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/NpYwE/).*

The example works great on Google's above mentioned documentation page, so I know its something I'm doing. Any ideas?

#### EDIT: I got the css from google's site, but still the problem persists.

Below is the code causing the problems:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Places Autocomplete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="CSS/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

    <style>
      input {
        border: 1px solid  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }
      input.notfound {
        border: 2px solid  rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
      }
    </style>

    <script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('searchTextField'));
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    input.className = '';
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
      input.className = 'notfound';
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  function setupClickListener(id, types) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
      autocomplete.setTypes(types);
    });
  }

  setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
  setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel" style="margin-left: -260px">
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
      <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
      <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
      <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</lable>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blank page when I use FusionTablesLayer with Google Maps JavaScript API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789004/blank-page-when-i-use-fusiontableslayer-with-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)

Comment: You need the css also.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks, I've updated the fiddle with the css included on the site. its better but it still fails to render properly and now the functionality of the search bar is lost.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks, the code fails in the fiddle but works in my local machine. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JS field doesn't accept Google Maps API library for external resources. (I'm not sure why)
So you need to insert <script>tag into the body field.

And JS field generates "window.onload" automatically.
You don't have to write "google.maps.event.addDomListener" in JS field.

[image]
http://jsfiddle.net/wf9a5m75/NpYwE/27/

```
<div id="panel" style="margin-left: -260px">
    <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
    <label for="changetype-all">All</label>
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
    <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
    <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</lable>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the 'external sources feature' but this works much better. +1

Answer (score 1):

You will notice the errors in the javascript console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fiddle.jshell.net/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined fiddle.jshell.net/agconti/NpYwE/show/:133
```

You aren't including the google API script correctly on the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt think to inspect the fiddle and check the errors there +1.