# Fusion Tables Search and Zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Feel like I am loosing my mind as I have no idea what it is I am missing. I am trying to replicate the example used at https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/search_and_zoom exactly the same way it is on that page for Fusion Table ID `1IYJMddMoWgwjieq3rwh8YyiHVpZy_1--hoNrPPa2`

The code given is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
  Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
 -->
 <html>
   <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Fusion Tables Layer Example: Search and Zoom</title>

<link href="/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
    var defaultCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10);
    var defaultZoom = 2;
    var tableId = '1ZU8D1ASYZMeIise2gboBt-HPt9hX8Y2NIdMfZg';
    var locationColumn = 'lat';
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: defaultCenter,
      zoom: defaultZoom,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: locationColumn,
        from: tableId
      },
      map: map
    });

    var zoomToAddress = function() {
      var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
      geocoder.geocode({
        address: address
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(10);

          // OPTIONAL: run spatial query to find results within bounds.
          var sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
          var ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
          var where = 'ST_INTERSECTS(' + locationColumn +
              ', RECTANGLE(LATLNG' + sw + ', LATLNG' + ne + '))';
          layer.setOptions({
            query: {
              select: locationColumn,
              from: tableId,
              where: where
            }
          });
        } else {
          window.alert('Address could not be geocoded: ' + status);
        }
      });
    };

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('search'),
             'click', zoomToAddress);
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'keypress', function(e) {
           if (e.keyCode == 13) {
             zoomToAddress();
           }
         });
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('reset'),
             'click', function() {
               map.setCenter(defaultCenter);
               map.setZoom(defaultZoom);
               layer.setOptions({
                 query: {
                   select: locationColumn,
                   from: tableId
                 }
               });
             });
       }

       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="map-canvas"></div>
     <div>
       <label>Enter an address:</label>
       <input type="text" id="address" value="Mountain View, CA">
       <input type="button" id="search" value="Search!">
       <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset">
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I've literally just replaced:

```
 var defaultCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10);
 var defaultZoom = 2;
 var tableId = '1ZU8D1ASYZMeIise2gboBt-HPt9hX8Y2NIdMfZg';
 var locationColumn = 'lat';
```

with:

```
 var defaultCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.927758210970154, 150.95845901699215);
 var defaultZoom = 10;
 var tableId = '1IYJMddMoWgwjieq3rwh8YyiHVpZy_1--hoNrPPa2';
 var locationColumn = 'col3';
```

I thought it would then just work but the map itself wont display. I then thought I'd use the example code and test that without changing it but it wont work either.

What have I missed?! Completely clueless to what Ive done wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blank page when I use FusionTablesLayer with Google Maps JavaScript API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789004/blank-page-when-i-use-fusiontableslayer-with-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)

Answer (score 0):

The included stylesheet may not be loaded(the path will only work when the document is located at google-developers.appspot.com), therefore #map-canvas doesn't have a height.

Assign a height or load the stylesheet via https://google-developers.appspot.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css